# How can I link a parallel button to handleclick to make OR Boolean?

Tags: android

```
public void HandleClick(View arg0) {
    if(!rolling) {
        rolling=true;

        dice_picture.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice3droll);
        dice_picture2.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice3droll);

        dice_sound.play(sound_id,1.0f,1.0f,0,0,1.0f);
        vy.vibrate(30);
        timer.schedule(new Roll(), 400);
    }
```

Comment: Can you expand on your question? Is there a problem in this code?

Comment: Well Sir, the code running properly but my wish is to link parallel button to public void handleclik, More eleborately, when hadleclick button clicked is does the job and I want to add Or statement to handle click button to control